# SSLSocket on Android does not fail on certificate with invalid server name

Tags: android, ssl

Here's the code I'm using to test the `SSLSocket` instances returned by `SSLCertificateSocketFactory` against https://badssl.com:

```
SSLCertificateSocketFactory factory = (SSLCertificateSocketFactory) SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getDefault(0);
mSocket = factory.createSocket();
factory.setHostname(mSocket, host);
mSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, 443), timeout);
mInput = mSocket.getInputStream();
mOutput = mSocket.getOutputStream();
```

This code works when connecting to `badssl.com:443`, throws an exception as expected when connecting to `expired.badssl.com:443` or `self-signed.badssl.com:443`, but **does not throw** when connecting to `wrong.host.badssl.com:443`.

In case this makes a difference, note that all hostnames on https://badssl.com appear to share a single IP, so configuring the `SSLSocket` for SNI is required.

PS: This was observed on a Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;TR: given your code it will not check the hostname at all.

From the [documentation of SSLCertificateSocketFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.html):

> Most SSLSocketFactory implementations do not verify the server's identity, allowing man-in-the-middle attacks. This implementation does check the server's certificate hostname, but **only for createSocket variants that specify a hostname**. When using methods that use InetAddress or which return an unconnected socket, you MUST verify the server's identity yourself to ensure a secure connection.

Thus it should check the socket if you are using `fcreateSocket(hostname,...)`. But it will not check the name if you are using `createSocket()` like you did because it does not know the hostname for checking. The `setHostname` call is only to set the SNI TLS extension.